# shell script which copies a file from a particular location(UNIX server) to a remote location(windows server)

Tags: shell, unix, ftp, sftp, telnet

I need to write a shell script which copies a file present at a location in UNIX server to a remote windows server with specified location. I am a novice in UNIX. Please advise how to do that.

Comment: What are your security requirements? Is this a security sensitive file? Is it going over your intranet or over the Internet?

Comment: @Kaz there are no security requirements. It has to be done over intranet.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the flavour of Unix, you may be able to install Samba (or already have it installed).  Then what you can do is:

- Share the target drive on your Windows back
- Mount the share using its UNC (i.e. //servername/sharename)

Use normal `cp` to copy the files

See [mount.cifs](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html) and [Samba Docs](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/)